# Not sure how to implement the following algorithm

Tags: java, android, algorithm, math, bitmap

I am trying to implement Histogram/image Equalization on a coloured image. I am not sure if I have implemented it correct because the screen just goes black every time I apply it to a bitmap image. The algorithm is called `histogram equalization`.

---

The part of my code that does the Histogram Equalization calculation:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {

            A = (pixels[index] >> 24) & 0xFF;
            R = (pixels[index] >> 16) & 0xFF;
            G = (pixels[index] >> 8) & 0xFF;
            B = pixels[index] & 0xFF;

            R = Math.round(((R - cumR[minR]) / (cumR[maxR] - cumR[minR])) * 255);
            G = Math.round(((G - cumG[minG]) / (cumG[maxG] - cumG[minG])) * 255);
            B = Math.round(((B - cumB[minB]) / (cumB[maxB] - cumB[minB])) * 255);

            returnBitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));

            ++index;
        }
    }
```

The image appears black once my code is applied, why doesnt it display an equalized image?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @home woops, updated now. sorry

Comment: what is `minR`? you comparing this to value of pixel, and then you setted ther position of pixel? for images larger than 16x16pixels `minR` will be `width*height-1` and i dont think you want this

Comment: @user902383 hi, I indeed did want the index as I use it for the final calculation. For example: cdfR[minR]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I was able to find a `Histogram Equalization` using a `LUT` example for `Java` and it is a better option than converting it to another `Color Space` such as [RGB to YUV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV).

With minimal modification, I was able to use the following code:

[Histogram Equalization for Java](http://zerocool.is-a-geek.net/?p=269)

Answer (score 1):

You're not calculating the histograms correctly. You shouldn't have a histogram spot for each pixel, you have one for each value[0..255]. You want to count how many pixels have that value, not the total "value" of red.

Here's a good way to get the histogram(and cumulative) for an image. It should get you started on the right path.

```
// generate histogram channels
// histogram arrays should be [0...255]
for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
    R = (pixels[i] >> 16) & 0xFF;
    G = (pixels[i] >> 8) & 0xFF;
    B = pixels[i] & 0xFF;

    histoR[R]++;
    histoG[G]++;
    histoB[B]++;  
}

// generate cumulative histograms
cumR[0] = histoR[0];
cumG[0] = histoG[0];
cumB[0] = histoB[0];
for(int i=1;i<histoR.length;i++){
    cumR[i] = histoR[i] + histoR[i-1];
    cumG[i] = histoG[i] + histoG[i-1];
    cumB[i] = histoB[i] + histoB[i-1];
}
```

Comment: +1 thanks heaps but I am not sure how to calculate the equalized image as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Once the histogram you have is correct, you just need to follow the steps in the slideshow you linked. Just make sure you understand what's it's saying, and code it up. If you want complete, ready-to-publsh code, there are numerous graphics libraries you can use.

Comment: Do you know any names of those libraries?